# Google Scholar Content Gone

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-index, google-scholar

The content on my website was on Google Scholar but now is gone. We added the `citation_title` class to the element containing our articles titles. We also modified the style of that class so it is the largest on the page. To the author listings we added the `citation_author` class as the docs stated. None of these have had an affect though, we resubmitted 7 weeks ago and still have no content there.

We are using both Dublin Core and Prism meta tags, could that be causing us to look like we are bloating the content of our page and penalizing us?

Here's an example of our meta tags:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/article/1" />
<meta name="citation_title" content="Article Title" />
<meta name="DC.title" content="Article Title" />
<meta name="citation_author" content="John D. Smith" />
<meta name="DC.creator" content="John D. Smith" />
<meta name="DC.issued" content="1970/01/01" />
<meta name="citation_publication_date" content="1970/01/01" />
<meta name="citation_journal_title" content="Journal Name" />
<meta name="citation_issue" content="1" />
<meta name="DC.citation.issue" content="1" />
<meta name="citation_firstpage" content="e1" />
<meta name="citation_lastpage" content="e1" />
<meta name="DC.citation.spage" content="e1" />
<meta name="citation_pdf_url" content="https://example.com/article-pdf/1" />
<meta name="citation_fulltext_html_url" content="https://example.com/article/1" />
<meta name="citation_doi" content="DOI/1" />
<meta name="citation_issn" content="Our ISSN" />
```

Does anyone have any recommendations for what we can do, or how we can contact Google about this? All forms I have found have been returned with no-reply addresses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like either something changed on your website or Google has updated its rules and re-evaluated the content.

---

### The Requirements

To have your article indexed in Google Scholar, the website hosting it has to comply with some requirements. [Google Scholar Guidlines](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#overview)

There are also a few other rules such as the pdf cannot exceed 5mb etc.

also worth checking your robots text so that the below is added.

**User-agent:** Googlebot

**Allow:** /

---

### Submitting an article

Failing that, try submitting directly at https://partnerdash.google.com/partnerdash/d/scholarinclusions
Can take around 4 weeks to show, but should be a more direct path.

Comment: I did the re-inclusion already, 7 weeks ago. It had no result. The PDFs are less than 5 MB and Googlebot is allowed. The pages are indexed in Google, they've been removed from the Scholar page though.

Comment: If you believe you have done everything correctly, the best thing to do I would try to contact the scholar helpdesk on this link. https://support.google.com/scholar/contact/general

Comment: Thanks, I was looking all over the place for a contact form.

Comment: They don't monitor that form. The team also doesn't have any sort of support for standard users. To really get help one needs the email address of a Google exec. It is very disappointing that they don't have support. I'll provide an update when I actually know about the prism/dublin tags. As a note for future visitors... Gsuite support can't help, nor maps support , nor Google for Business, nor Play support, nor the product forums, nor the provided email address they give out.

Answer (score 2):

If you continue to reach out to Google and their various departments you can reach someone at the Scholar team. It takes about eight months. They do not appear to monitor the form they tell users to submit with. The issue with our content was related to Google Scholar bot not having access to our content. We had to add a subscription for their bot so they'd have access. Additionally the dublin core tags are not required, highwire press tags are sufficient.